# How to create own GUI component in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to do some people administration application and i would like to use own component. I have a listBox with actions and i would like to show people who are in list in selected action. There is no problem for me to show just their names in another list, but i would like to have a pane where would be a card (my component) for every person asociated with that action. That card should look like

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="296" Margin="668,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230">
        <Image x:Name="image" Height="124" Width="226"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name: " FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy2" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="151"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Surname: " FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy3" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy7" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Birthday: " FontSize="18"/>
        <DatePicker Width="136" DisplayDate="2016-06-27" DisplayDateStart="1950-01-01" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" SelectedDate="{Binding Selected.DatumOdjezdu}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
```

So there are two problems for me.

1. How to create own component.
2. How to create a pane(it can be scrollable), where would be as many those cards as needed.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 8):

WPF offers more than one way to achieve your goal.

It depends on your Application, what fits your needs the most.

You can reach this by

- [DataTemplates](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html)
- [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [CustomControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control)

Here some more Info about the [Differences of UserControl and CustomControl](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html)

Depending on your posted Code, i'd suggest a DataTemplate in your case.